# Saving mouse click coordinates on a matplotlib figure to a list in Python and disconnect from figure after a single click

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I am trying to save left mouse click coordinates to a list from a matplotlib figure. Here's what I have written so far:

```py
def onclick(event):
    
    coord = [event.xdata,event.ydata]
    print(coord)
    return coord


def locate():
    
    fig = plt.gcf()
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
```

As you have probably figured from my code, I am new to Python. With the above code, I am not able to return the `coord`. I tried making `coord` a `global` variable but didn't get the result.
I want to disconnect from the figure after a single mouse click and also save the coordinates as  a list.
Basically , I want the statement  `coordinates = locate()`  save the list to the variable `coordinates`.
I am working in a Juypter Notebook.

A similar question : [get Coordinates of matplotlib plot figure python with mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424626/get-coordinates-of-matplotlib-plot-figure-python-with-mouse-click)

Comment: Hi Did you found a solution for this? Can you please provide some sample code, so it will be useful for the SO community.  I am also looking for a similar approach. thanks

Comment: No, Not really the way I wanted it. I used pyqtgraph and made it to always listen for click events on the plot area. Then I kept replacing the value of a global variable with mouse coordinates.

Here is a similar question I asked for pyqtgraph : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759625/return-mouse-click-coordinates-as-a-list-from-a-pyqtgraph