# Return mouse click coordinates as a list from a pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, mouseclick-event

I am quite new to pyqtgraph and have been learning python for some time. I am trying to get mouse click coordinates from the pyqtgraph plotitem.
Here's what I have so far.

```py
class CrossHair():
    def __init__(self, win,row=0,col=0):
        self.label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
        self.p1 = win.getItem(row=row,col=col)
        self.p1.setAutoVisible(x=True,y=True)
        win.addItem(self.label,row=row,col=col)
        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
        self.vb = self.p1.vb
        self.p1.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.p1.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.p1.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=self.mouseMoved)
        self.p1.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(self.mouseClicked)
        #self.p1.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouseMoved)
    def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
        if self.p1.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            mousePoint = self.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            self.label.setText("<span style='font-size: 10pt'>x=%0.1f,   <span style='color: red'>y=%0.1f</span>"%(mousePoint.x(),mousePoint.y()))
            self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
            self.hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())
    def mouseClicked(self,event):
        global mouse_coordinates
        mouse_coordinates=[]
        pos = event.scenePos()
        mousePoint = self.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        mouse_coordinates = [mousePoint.x(),mousePoint.y()]
        return mouse_coordinates
        #self.sigMouseClicked.disconnect()
```

I want to define a function `get_points(win)` which takes the current pyqtgraph window, draws a crosshair and whenever I click, returns a list of mouse click coordinates. After a single click, I don't want it to register any more coordinates unless the I call the function again.

I wrote something like this but it did not work:

```py
def get_points(win):
    ch = CrossHair(win)
    ch.p1.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(ch.mouseClicked)
```

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: function executed by `event` doesn't know what to do with values which you send with `return` and you can't change it - so using `return` is usless. You have to add points to global `mouse_coordinates` or to `self.mouse_coordinates`. And later other function should get values from global `mouse_coordinates` or `self.mouse_coordinates`.

Comment: GUI frameworks doesn't work like `input()` - it will not wait for end of your function `get_points` but it will create crosshair, assign `mouseClicked` and go back to main code. If you have to use points then do it directly in `mouseClicked`

Comment: I did try adding self.MOUSE_COORDINATES to CrossHair class. 
 And in the get_points(win) function, I defined :
 ```def get_points(win):
    ch = CrossHair(win)
    ch.p1.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(ch.mouseClicked)
    return ch.MOUSE_COORDINATES
```
However, this does not register any clicks, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: as I sad before GUI works different then `input()` - it doesn't wait for your mouse (it has to run other elements at this time) - so your `get_points()` (and `return ch.MOUSE_COORDINATES`) is execute before you even try to click and it can't get coordinates. If you need to use coordinate then do it directly in `mouseClicked`